# Health check failed in dynamic port set-up in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

My ECS set-up keeps on failing in health check when I set it up with dynamic port.

Here is my set-up:

I have a spring-boot web app which uses port 10440. So in my Task Definition I use port 0 as my Host Port to enable dynamic porting and 10440 as my container port. I have two 2 ec2 instances and run 2 task in my service. But my task are keep on terminating due to failing health check.

Screenshots:

-[Task event logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgIP7.png)

-[Unhealthy regitered ec2 instances in target group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRjd8.png)

Note: If change my Host port to 10440 also, the set-up works fine. But I cannot run more task than the number of ec2 instance.

Screenshot:
[Health registered ec2 instance in target group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF9GG.png)

I hope someone can help so I can setup my ECS to run more task in 2 instances. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure out the problem. Upon executing

aws elbv2 describe-target-health --target-group-arn

I have found out that health check is having a timeout error, so I just prolong the timeout in health check setting.

Comment: i have a similar error with wordpress containers. What are your timeout values in health check ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and got to know that in the ECS  cluster security group, Dynamic ports (All TCP ports) not allowed to ALB sg. Once it is allowed traffic port should able to connect to EC2 instance then health check will pass

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the port for your health-check of your target group is set to "traffic port".

[image]